# google maps: show map based on country name or ISO

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Just trying out something for fun.

In my database I have countries as name and iso - i would like to call geocode() with one or the other and get a fixation on that region.

```
    var country_name = $('div#start-country-name').data('countryname');
    var location_coord = $('div#start-location-coord').data('locationcoord'); // array of locations in that country

    var map;
    var geocoder;
    var marker;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("view-the-map"),myOptions);
    }

initialize();

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': country_name}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      draggable:false,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
} else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
});
```

Sadly it only shows - blank 
And all is loaded aso.

Any ideas or pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Can u give url to your code

Comment: Try this example: http://jsbin.com/sumogagobi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Super .. I works perfect.